# In SARIMA model do we start by first differences or seasonal differences?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, differencing

I don't know the general formula for SARIMA model for additive and multiplicative model.
I don't know whether we start by first differences or seasonal differences.
I only know the formula of differences when the number exceeds 1. For example when it equals 1 we do $$ w_t = y_t(1-B^s) $$ but when it's 2 for example the B will change to D $$ z_t = y_t(1-B^s)(1-D^s).$$
What is the general formula ?

Comment: Using punctuation may help make your text more understandable...

Answer (score 2):

Seasonal difference, then normal difference.

From https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html

> The data are clearly non-stationary, with some seasonality, so we will first take a seasonal difference. The seasonally differenced data are shown in Figure 8.18. These also appear to be non-stationary, so we take an additional first difference